# How to explain basic transistor, diode etc. principles to High Schoolers

Tags: transistors

I have an electronics/science club at my school, and I was trying to explain basic principles of how transistors can act as a switch and amplify and then build a little water-detector circuit the next week. I was having a hard time explaining to them and they just couldn't quite understand.

Are there any suggestions on how to explain electronic concepts (specifically transistors) on a level to be understandable by high-schoolers?

Comment: I highly recommend using the transistor video on Make magazine's YouTube channel for a more detailed explanation as well as history. That video is actually a bit more specific to the BJT

Comment: What about your explanation did they not understand? Are you trying to explain the underlying physics? The utility? Application? Practice? Mathematical models? There is quite a lot that could be explained about transistors, even to highschoolers.

Comment: You can take a horse to water but you can't make it drink. This is more about teachering skills and the attentiveness of the average pupil than electronics.

Comment: Maybe the transistor concept is a bit too much for them to grasp, considering average students. Maybe you should just focus on voltage and current first (i.e. lighting up a few LEDs). Or maybe you could abstract away the complexities of transistors if you really must include them in the circuits you will be building.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I explain them in a course for radio amateurs studying for their UK Full Licence

SEMICONDUCTORS, DIODES AND TRANSISTORS

ELECTRONS AND HOLES

Let's think of a row of pennies laid out in a line, touching, across a table. Move the right hand end penny one penny's width to the right, leaving a gap. Then keep moving the penny to the left of the gap into the space. As you proceed all the pennies have moved to the right, and the gap has moved across the table to the left. Now picture the pennies as electrons, and you can see how electrons moving one way across a semiconductor causes holes to move the opposite way.

To stretch the analogy, we could use little piles of pennies, so a lot have to move right before a hole moves left. Or we could have a few pennies and a lot of space so that holes travel easily as the sparse pennies are moved across the wide gaps. These two cases model the two forms of doped Silicon, lot of electrons added and we have N-type, lots of holes (electrons removed) and we have P-type. The types are achieved by mixing (doping) the Silicon with small quantities of other metals.

With the electrons having to struggle through the atoms of a semiconductor, its resistivity is relatively high. Early semiconductors used Germanium, but, except for special cases, nowadays Silicon is the universal choice.

Copper wire can be visualised as having big piles of penny electrons, all close together, so a current is the movement of the few pennies at the tops of the piles, no holes are produced at all. With so many available for the current, resistivity, as we know, is low.

DIODE

The commonest semiconductor diode (there are other specialised types) has a junction between N-type and P-type, where the two types are fused together. If a voltage is applied to the diode, positive to the N-type end and negative to the other, the electrons are all pulled to the positive end, leaving holes at the negative end. With hardly any electrons in the middle, almost no current can flow. The diode is "reverse biassed"

When the voltage is applied the other way, negative to the N-type end and positive to the P-type, electrons are attracted to the middle and can cross over to cancel out the holes in the P-type, and flow out into the connecting wire. At the other, negative voltage, end, electrons are repelled into the middle of the diode, to be replaced by those flooding in from the wire, so overall a current can flow easily: the diode is forward biassed.

The connections to a diode are called the "Anode" which is the positive end when the diode is forward biassed, and the "Cathode" which is the negative end. I remember these by analogy with the same terms for valves, which need a high positive voltage (H.T. for "High Tension" -- keep your fingers off) at the anode for current to flow. A good mnemonic for the polarity of a forward biassed diode might be PPNN: "Positive, P-type, N-type, Negative".

A varactor diode exploits the fact that two separated charge areas, positive and negative, make a crude capacitor. So, specially designed diodes are made to exploit this, when reversed biassed. The applied voltage pulls the charges apart, forming a "depletion layer" between the contacts. Increasing the applied reverse voltage makes this sparse layer wider, so reducing the capacity, and vice versa. Varactor diodes are commonly used in tuned circuits to vary the frequency, replacing the vaned capacitors that were used in the days of valves.

BIPOLAR TRANSISTOR

A bipolar transistor is one whose operation depends on both electrons and holes. It comprises two diodes back to back sharing a common central layer. One of the outer terminals is the Collector C and the other is the Emitter E. The central connection is the Base B, and it is part of both the CB and BE diodes. So we have a three layered sandwich. In normal use the diode between C and B is reverse biassed, so, without the presence of the BE diode and its effect, no current would flow, because all the electrons are pulled up to one end of the CB section, and the holes to the other end, as in a diode, by the applied voltage.

The BE diode is forward biassed, so a current can flow and the external circuit is set up to limit this to a fairly small value, but there is still a lot of holes and electrons flowing through the Base and Emitter.

Now the clever bit. The common connection of the CB and BE diodes at the Base is made very thin, so the flood of electrons and holes in the BE part replace those that the reverse Collector voltage has pulled away, and a current can now flow though this CB diode in the reverse direction, and then on through the forward biassed BE junction to the Emitter and out into the external circuit.

I think it is obvious that you can't make a transistor by soldering two diodes back to back, the action requires that intimate sharing of the thin layer inside the Silicon.

The Collector current depends on there being a Base current flowing, and the transistor is designed so that a small current in the BE diode opens the way for a much larger current in the CB junction. Thus we have current amplification. Using voltage drops across external resistors, this can be converted into voltage amplification.

These transistors are called "bipolar" because they effectively have two junctions.

I have carefully avoided mentioning the type of material in the CB and BE diodes, the ideas are the same for both, and we can have NPN or PNP as the possible layers. The arrow, on the emitter, in the symbol, which shows the direction of the conventional Collector current (the opposite of electron flow), points in the direction of the negative side of the applied CE voltage, so the current is "out of N or into P at the emitter".

FIELD EFFECT TRANSISTOR, or FET

There are lots of different designs of FET, and this is a very simplistic look at their basic principle.

These are "unipolar" transistors, although the term is not often used, because their operation depends only on electrons and electric fields, not holes.

Here we have a single block of doped silicon, the "channel", with lumps of the opposite type on the sides, or as an encircling ring. So we have only one diode junction, which is called the Gate G, between the lumps or ring and the channel. The channel acts as a resistor, with current flowing though from one end, the source S, to the other the Drain D. The junction between gate and channel is reverse biassed, so no current flows, but there is an electric field set up which pulls charges, electrons or holes, to the sides of the channel, leaving less available for the SD current. Thus we have the SD current controlled by the voltage on the gate.

Note this is a voltage controlled device, virtually no current flows into or out of the Gate. Think of Ohm's law: Resistance = Volts/Amps, and we see that a very low current means a very high Resistance, so the FET is said to have a very high input impedance -- its main advantage over Bi-Polar, where, by contrast, it takes little voltage to send the current through the base, giving it a low input impedance

Answer (score 2):

First they have to understand voltage and current.  When they do, the basic operation of a transistor is not hard to explain.

To simplify things, I'd stick to NPN and N channel.  You can introduce PNP and P channel after they are comfortable with the basic operation of N devices.  For a NPN BJT, a little current thru B-E allows a lot of current thru C-E.  For N channel MOSFET, D-S is like a switch that is off when the gate is at 0 V, and on when the gate is at 5 V or 12 V, depending on the particular part.

There are lots of nuances and some FETs operate differently, but I would introduce only these basics at first.  Actually I'd pick either a NPN or NFET to start with, let them get comfortable with that, then introduce either more details of that part or different parts at a similar broad level.

FETs are probably a little easier to conceptualize at first, but are harder to work with experimentally.  I'd probably chose a basic and reasonably robust NPN transistor, like the 2N4401, for starters.  These come in TO-92 packages, so are easy to plug into breadboards, are dirt cheap, and actually pretty hard to to blow up if you're using a few batteries for the power supply.

Just ignore ESD issues for now.  These devices can be damaged by ESD, but nowhere near as easily as a MOSFET.  Get 100 2N4401 and another 100 2N4403 for later when you get to PNP transistors.  There are lots and lots of simple projects you can do with these, even with just a very basic understanding of BJTs.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you taught the classes in the wrong order.  The theory is a lot easier to understand after you have experimented with a practical example.  I would have started with the water detector circuit, and introduced it something like this:

1. Have them try detecting the water without a transistor.  Why is it so quiet?  Use a multimeter to measure the current through the water.
2. Have them add the transistor into the circuit.  Why did it get louder?  Use a multimeter to measure the current through the transistor.
3. Show an oscilloscope trace of a transistor amplifying a sine wave.
4. *Now* explain how the transistor works.

Comment: Personally I always hated those kind of lessons. Much of the information you see from watching the demo is lost because there is no context yet in your mind to hang it on. Good information transfer is all about context. Basically, people don't remember stuff if they have no context to associate the new information with. If you do a brief introduction of the device first, then they can actually *understand* what they are seeing. Otherwise, it's just a magic show, which may be entertaining, but its not educational. It can also be very frustrating for those that really want to learn.

Comment: Fully agree with Olin.

Comment: Karl's approach appears iterative.  He continues going back to the experiment as context is added.  I prefer to mix theory and practice, rather than going through all of one before going through all of the other.